# operating system and relationship with word size

Tags: operating-system

Suppose RAM size is 4GB means 2^32 Bytes and 64 bit OS.
So word size is 64bits=2^3 Bytes.
So no of words in RAM is 2^32 / 2^3=2^29  Words.
So if system is word addressable than only 29 bits is needed to address the memory . So what 64-29=35bits is doing?

Answer (score 0):

A 64-bit OS can *theoretical* access over 16 million TB of RAM. With 4GB, that OS can't access its full *potential*, **so those excess bits aren't used**. If an OS tried to read/write past the amount of given RAM, undefined results will be returned. So why waste all of those bits?

It's going to take some time to get over 16 million TB of RAM into a personal computer. The idea is, even though more RAM will be available in future, the 64-bit OS will still be able access it **without** breaking compatibility.

For example, if you had a 34-bit OS with maxed out RAM, you'd need to upgrade to a new chip, like a 35-bit one, to get more RAM. Imagine how much work and money it would cost to do that every time you needed more RAM!